# InverseJS plugins like Converse.js

Tags: xmpp, converse.js

Does Inverse.js (sharing the same source code as Converse.js) support custom developer plugin, like Converse.js ? The same way as Converse.js ?

Comment: Inverse.js used to be a fullpage version of Converse.js but it's been merged into Converse.js and is no longer a separate code-base.

Comment: when was the merge ?